# How to customize SVM non-linear descision boudary in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I want to train a SVM with non-linear boundary. The boundary is known, expressed with formula
y = sgn( (w11*x1+ w12*x2 + w13*x3)* (w21*x4+ w22*x5 + w23*x6) ), where [x1 x2 ... x6] are 1-bit inputs, [w11 w12 w13 w21 w22 w23] are unknown parameters.

How can I learn [w11 w12 w13 w21 w22 w23] with train data?

Answer (score 0):

SVM is not an algorithm for such task. SVM has its own criterion to maximize, which has nothing to do with the decision boundary shape (ok, not nothing, but it is hard to convert one to another). Obviously, one can try to predefine custom kernel function to do so, but this task seems as almost unsolvable problem (I can't think of any reproducing hilbert space with such decision boundaries).

In short: your question is a bit like "how to make a watermelon remove nails from the wall?". Obviously - you can do some pretty hard "magic" to do so, but this is not what watermelons are for.

Comment: Thanks, I also realized it's not quite relevent. My problem is kind of more like parameter estimation. For SVM , is the boundary generated based on kernel function ? Which is automatic, so I can only customize kernel function, rather than customize boundary.

Comment: Decision boundary follows from the projection of the kernel space based hyperplane onto the input space. SVM is not about "fitting a separating curve" into data, which you seem to look for. Although your model is quite simple, you should be just fine by performing simple gradient based optimization on equivalent error function

Comment: Ja, you are right. I'm trying the model based on multiplication of several linear predictor with lr to aproximate the parameters. It's more reasonable.